# Getting the correct variable out of an array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to figure out exactly how the data will be shaped, and how to get out the value I want from this:

```
$items[$qid] = _content_sync_server_prepare($entity, $entity_type);
```

`_content_sync_server_prepare()` will return this - `return array('entity_type' => $entity_type, 'entity' => $entity);`

and $qid is a variable representing a number.

I want to get, for each $qid value, the $entity_type value.

I believe I would use a foreach loop as such:

```
foreach ($items as $item => $value) {
$entity_type_value = $item[$value];
}
```

Am I correct? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be the right way:

```
foreach($items as $key => $value) {
    $entity_type_value = $value['entity_type'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach statement will not work since $item is a string and not an array.

Following should work (untested):

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $entity_type_value = $item['entity_type'];
}
```